# Undeclared identifier error in fast enumeration loop

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, identifier

I've been trying to write an app for a deck of cards, but I keep getting an error in my code. The error is on `otherCard` and says

> undeclared identifier otherCard.

```
#define MATCH_BONUS 4
#define MISMATCH_PENALTY 2
#define FLIP_COST 1

- (void)flipCardAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    card *card = [self cardAtIndex:index];

    if (!card.isUnplayable){
        if(!card.isFaceUp){
            for (card *otherCard in self.cards) {
                if (otherCard.isFaceUp && !otherCard.isUnplayable) {
                    int matchscore = [card match: @[otherCard]];
                    if (matchscore) {
                        otherCard.unplayable = YES;
                        card.unplayable = YES;
                        self.score += matchscore * MATCH_BONUS;
                    } else {
                        otherCard.faceUp = NO;
                        self.score -= MISMATCH_PENALTY;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            self.score -= FLIP_COST;
        }
        card.faceUp = !card.isFaceUp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it tell you what line the error is on?

Comment: Change your `card` class to `Card`. You're masking it locally, so the for each loop is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Your `card` class is being masked by the `card` variable.

```
card *card = [self cardAtIndex:index];
```

This means the for each loop fails here:

```
for (card *otherCard in self.cards) {
```

Try changing your `card` class to `Card` with a capital C (capitalizing class names is good style too). Alternately, you could rename the `card` variable to something else like `flipCard`.